# Expo SplashScreen Standalone Build Failed

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to build my application at Expo but I have the following problem:

[Error Expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03jSk.png)

When looking at the build error log, I have the following message:

```
Using manifest: {"ios":{"supportsTablet":true,"userInterfaceStyle":"light"},"web":{"favicon":"./assets/favicon.png"},"icon":"./assets/icon.png","name":"Porta do Sol","slug":"portaDoSol","splash":{"image":"./assets/splash.png","imageUrl":"https://d1wp6m56sqw74a.cloudfront.net/~assets/761e4c800ce1de9fd90da12f45687087","resizeMode":"contain","backgroundColor":"#ffffff"},"android":{"package":"com.interface.portadosol","userInterfaceStyle":"light"},"iconUrl":"https://d1wp6m56sqw74a.cloudfront.net/~assets/5aab62d1ae6a0f65e10f12c0e55d20dd","locales":{},"updates":{"fallbackToCacheTimeout":0},"version":"0.0.1","platforms":["ios","android","web"],"entryPoint":"./index.js","sdkVersion":"38.0.0","orientation":"portrait","dependencies":["@react-native-community/masked-view","@react-navigation/drawer","@react-navigation/native","@react-navigation/stack","expo","expo-splash-screen","expo-sqlite","expo-status-bar","expo-updates","native-base","react","react-dom","react-native","react-native-appearance","react-native-gesture-handler","react-native-reanimated","react-native-safe-area-context","react-native-screens","react-native-svg","react-native-svg-charts","react-native-web","sqlite"],"bundledAssets":["asset_3a2ba31570920eeb9b1d217cabe58315.ttf","asset_8b12b3e16d591abc926165fa8f760e3b.json","asset_744ce60078c17d86006dd0edabcd59a7.ttf","asset_461d9bba8b6a3c91675039df12cfe6ca.json","asset_140c53a7643ea949007aa9a282153849.ttf","asset_94c4ffdcbffeb0570c635d7f8edd8a25.json","asset_ca9ce9ff0676a9b04ef0f8a3ad17dd08.ttf","asset_54a5c98d22f313098b3dbe2d5b2e87ba.json","asset_b49ae8ab2dbccb02c4d11caaacf09eab.ttf","asset_39843e5d52a6c5c42d5abdb0b34bcaa6.json","asset_b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf","asset_f1f91feb805137c9283fb766620ec5eb.json","asset_09dd345dbd4ec5a0874841d5749ac153.json","asset_0886a6b127c6057cee83f9c65c7ffd62.json","asset_f6c6f6c8cb7784254ad00056f6fbd74e.ttf","asset_b70cea0339374107969eb53e5b1f603f.ttf","asset_c39278f7abfc798a241551194f55e29f.ttf","asset_e20945d7c929279ef7a6f1db184a4470.ttf","asset_60668d999bbaf663420340f7bdd580d7.json","asset_b2e0fc821c6886fb3940f85a3320003e.ttf","asset_3e6805fbc794680014716b8c752f20b8.json","asset_3c851d60ad5ef3f2fe43ebd263490d78.ttf","asset_1a0e3525dd5df87e77057204129a5e6e.json","asset_a37b0c01c0baf1888ca812cc0508f6e2.ttf","asset_7e078700f0c35367a56c5bbb2047dda7.json","asset_8e7f807ef943bff1f6d3c2c6e0f3769e.ttf","asset_fdc01171a7a7ea76b187afcd162dee7d.json","asset_d2285965fe34b05465047401b8595dd0.ttf","asset_647543ebfccf6e5495434383598453d1.json","asset_5cdf883b18a5651a29a4d1ef276d2457.ttf","asset_74d124a3caeac2bea111f3ca2f2dd34a.json","asset_7d40544b395c5949f4646f5e150fe020.png","asset_cdd04e13d4ec83ff0cd13ec8dabdc341.png","asset_a132ecc4ba5c1517ff83c0fb321bc7fc.png","asset_0ea69b5077e7c4696db85dbcba75b0e1.png","asset_f5b790e2ac193b3d41015edb3551f9b8.png","asset_5223c8d9b0d08b82a5670fb5f71faf78.png","asset_fd0192cf977ddf7b60b4e21e332f6b76.json","asset_15e61754d2d3825004eed075f496ae28.png","asset_778ffc9fe8773a878e9c30a6304784de.png","asset_376d6a4c7f622917c39feb23671ef71d.png","asset_c79c3606a1cf168006ad3979763c7e0c.png","asset_02bc1fa7c0313217bde2d65ccbff40c9.png","asset_35ba0eaec5a4f5ed12ca16fabeae451d.png"],"id":"@matheusms21/portaDoSol","releaseId":"c05eb142-056f-40e6-a330-79bd258d0e14","revisionId":"0.0.1-r.OkgIqpx_B","publishedTime":"2020-10-04T03:29:57.730Z","commitTime":"2020-10-04T03:29:57.793Z","bundleUrl":"https://d1wp6m56sqw74a.cloudfront.net/%40matheusms21%2FportaDoSol%2F0.0.1%2Fecb187f580b4c9bbd9873239fc05375e-38.0.0-android.js","releaseChannel":"default","hostUri":"exp.host/@matheusms21/portaDoSol"}
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk38/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/drawable/splashscreen.xml'
```

The strange thing is that yesterday I managed to finish the build, but today I have this error, and I did not make any changes to SplashScreen or anything like that.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Got the same build error. Just today. Let me know if you found any solution.

Comment: Now the build finished without the error.
It was probably their mistake that was corrected at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the build finished without the error.
It was probably their mistake that was corrected at this point.
Thank you all :)

Comment: Thanks, I got it as well. Please mention it in the answer that its expo internal error and try after some time.